# Store multiple records under the same ID in same table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've got a table to hold visits. Each time a client visits it needs to store a new record under the same ID number but with an updated visit number and other info.

I've got the visit number updating but I cannot store multiple records under the same ID. It just keeps overriding what record contained originally.

The form for the visit is linked to the table which should hold the data.
In fact, at the moment the table will only allow me to input one record total (why is this happening?)

How it works at the moment is that the user types in the ID of the client they wish to add a new visit for. The ID is put into the new form (linked to the visit table) and they can fill out the data accordingly.

How do I get my table to accept multiple records and how do I get multiple records under the same ID?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling your ID field is set to Indexed(No Duplicates).

This means that when inserting a value with the same ID it will fail to insert because it violates a key constraint.

I would have a VisitID(Indexed No Duplicates Auto Increment) and then a ClientID(Indexed Duplicates Ok)

Then load the Form and set ClientID instead to avoid the key constraint issue.

Then prior to Inserting the Value into the table collect the number of previous visits and insert that along with the data entered.

**Update**

SQL Query

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblVisits (ClientID,NumberofVisits,DateEntered) VALUES(" &  YourClientIDHERE & "," &  YourNumberofVisists & ",#" Now() & "# );"
Docmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

This will insert a row with the ClientID,NumberofVisitsCurrently, and the Date/Time the entry was committed. You may obviously alter this to add the additional data needed for visits.

If you need more help with this I think you should add some code to your question so that we can better assist you in building this

Comment: I have all of that set to what you said and I still cannot input more that one record or add multiple with the same ID
What exactly do you mean by set the ClientID upon the load?

Comment: @Victoria you stated "The ID is put into the new form (linked to the visit table) and they can fill out the data accordingly." What I am saying is you need to Use `ClientID` in place of this `ID` and link via `ClientID`. So when your form pulls up you would set the `ClientID` and let the Database determine the `VisitID` as a primary key via `Auto Increment`.

Comment: Right. Thank you!
But I'm hoping to put various ClientIDs each with their own VisitIDs in the same table

Comment: @Victoria yes this will work `VisitID` will just be a counter 1...Some Number. `ClientID` will be the link field to a "Client" as specified by the user entry in your question. this will allow a 1-toMany relationship between "Clients" and Visits. I have edited my answer to show you a query to perform this operation in Access.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (or rather, shouldn't) have multiple records under the same id, assuming that's your only key.  The point of the id column is to *uniquely* identify the record.

It sounds like you need to have a Clients table (with an id), and a Visits table (that also has an id) that points to the client with a client_id column.